# Business letterhead

Tags: letterhead

I'm new to LaTeX but I'm now able to create basic but nice-looking documents. I want to make LaTeX my only document-processing software, and would want to produce my company's letterhead. Can someone help, please? The letterhead has got a header and a footer, and logo, address, telephone number, fax number, and email. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a configurable, modern letter class like [`scrlttr2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scrlttr2). An example can be found, e.g., [here](https://komascript.de/node/1599). If you need more help, we need more information. In this case you should also add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of what you already have.

Comment: You can see at the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55928/business-letter-template-with-letterhead-on-the-side.

Comment: There are many letter classes in CTAN  and [templates](https://www.latextemplates.com/cat/cover-letters) and [more templates](https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/cover-letters) here and there. Take time to search, compare, and then decide if you need (1) just use some already done (2)   modify that cute template im some way ...  or (3) start from scratch with `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} Dear Sir, Sincerely, \end{document}`. If you get stuck with (2) or (3), ask about your specific problem but showing what are you trying (that is, a MWE).